# Roth IRA vs. Traditional for married couple with AGI over $120k?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, tax-deduction, retirement-plan

My wife and I have an AGI somewhere between $120k - $140k depending on how much I make on side gigs throughout the year. We both started new full-time jobs within the last 12 months.

Here is the background:

- We file jointly as "married"
- Her new job does not offer retirement benefits of any kind. Her income is about $38k/y
- My job has enrollment for a Traditional 401k with 3% match that I can enroll in starting in June. My income from this will be between $90-100k this year, plus I get some random 1099 work throughout the year.
- I plan to contribute $729 per pay period to my employer sponsored 401k. Over a full year, this would put me at the $17,500 max contribution.
- She has a few thousand sitting in a previous account from a previous employer. I have about $35k across a few 403(b)s. I'm happy with my 403(b) performance, so I likely won't roll over - she will roll over.

At first glance, it seems that the smart move is for her to open a Traditional IRA with somewhere like Vanguard so that we can write off the contributions. Then, [I read that if your AGI is over $115k](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/2013-IRA-Deduction-Limits-Effect-of-Modified-AGI-on-Deduction-if-You-Are-Covered-by-a-Retirement-Plan-at-Work) for the year, that you can't write off any of the 401k contributions. This seems like it would lead to paying taxes twice - once on the money going in, and then again when you begin to take a distribution. Is this true? What option does she have that's most advantageous from a tax perspective?

Also, I just pretend that I know what I'm talking about with this stuff, so if I've left out any important details, please feel free to ask!

Comment: For a non-deductible traditional IRA, earnings are taxed upon distribution but contributions are not. So there is no double taxation.

Comment: @CraigW what about the line in the link that I posted to - `$115,000 or more - no deduction` That to me says that you don't get to deduct your contributions from your taxes? Did I misunderstand it? How would that work, since she would be paying into it with taxed dollars since it wouldn't be withheld by the employer?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with married couples if only one is covered by a retirement plan at work. But regardless, if you were to make a non-deductible traditional IRA contribution, that money would be taxed like normal income that year. When you take a distribution, only the earnings portion of it would be taxed. Just clarifying that there would not be double taxation.

Comment: @CraigW: You are looking only at the nominal value of money, which is a very naive way to look at money. From the perspective of time value of money, principal now = principal + earnings later, so the earnings later are part of the principal now that has already been taxed. From your perspective, you might say that a Roth IRA is much better than a Traditional IRA, because earnings are not taxed in Roth, but are in reality, if tax rates are the same now and later, Roth IRA and Traditional IRA are the same. This makes sense if you consider principal now = principal + earnings later.

Comment: @CraigW: You might also say that deductible and non-deductible Traditional are the same, since in both cases, principal and earnings are each taxed once; but in reality, non-deductible Traditional IRA is much worse than deductible Traditional IRA, for the reason that the principal taxed now means the value of principal + earnings in the future have all been "taxed", to taxing the earnings again is effectively, "double taxation" on the value of the money.

Comment: @user102008 I was just clarifying to the OP that if they contribute $5k to a non-deductible traditional IRA and then take a distribution of $10k a while later, they pay taxes on $5k not $10k (or 50% if you take a partial distribution). The point is moot though because I see no reason why anybody would contribute to a non-deductible traditional IRA except to do an immediate Roth conversion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Forbes article [IRS Announces 2014 Retirement Plan Contribution Limits For 401(k)s And More](http://www.forbes.com/sites/ashleaebeling/2013/11/01/irs-announces-2014-retirement-plan-contribution-limits-for-401ks-and-more/) spells this out pretty clearly.

For your wife - "an IRA contributor who is not covered by a workplace retirement plan and is married to someone who is covered, the deduction is phased out if the couple’s income is between $181,000 and $191,000."

So, with your wife not covered by a 401(k), and your income below the stated limit, she can deduct the IRA contribution. When your income gets beyond that limit, she can make a non-deductible contribution and convert to Roth, if she wishes.